# Отображение точек эллипса в пространстве на 2D-плоскость

Tags: математика, геометрия, matlab

Всем доброго времени суток! Моя задача следующая: есть массив точек в пространстве, которые образуют эллипс, и этот массив надо спроектировать на изображение 2D (как если бы мы получали изображение с камеры). Моя проблема такова, что в некоторых случаях вместо эллипса я могу получить гиперболу, что не есть хорошо. Делаю я отображение в матлабе следующим образом:

```
function [u,v] = point2camProjection(point,f,Oc)
  
  K = [f,0,Oc(1);0,f,Oc(2);0,0,1];
  
  UVW = K*point;
  u=UVW(1)/UVW(3);
  v=UVW(2)/UVW(3); 
end
```

point - это координаты 3D-точки, f - фокусное расстояние камеры, Oc-оптический центр камеры.

Comment: Иногда эллипс может спроектироваться в параболу или гиперболу. Так устроена математика.

Comment: Это я понимаю, но как можно избежать таких случаев?

Comment: Если эллипс пересекает плоскость `Z = 0` вы получите гиперболу. Если касается её - параболу.